typesafe conversion of constant case string into an object
There is a library for configuration called nconf, one feature it has is to take environment variables and convert them into an object:
MYFOO_BAR_BAZ=true MYFOO_BAR_COUNT=34 MYFOO_REALLY_KABOOM=9000 tsx ./main.ts

// main.ts
import { options } from './options.ts';

console.log(options);

// options.ts
import * as nconf from 'nconf';
import home from 'user-home';

const KEY = 'MYFOO';
const ENV_SEPARATOR = `_`;
const ENV_PATTERN = new RegExp(`/^${KEY.toUpperCase()}${ENV_SEPARATOR}/`);
const RC_NAME = `.${KEY}rc.json`;

nconf.env({
  separator: ENV_SEPARATOR,
  match: ENV_PATTERN,
  lowerCase: true,
  parseValues: true,
  transform(obj: Record<string, string>) {
    obj.key.replace(ENV_PATTERN, '').toLowerCase();
    return obj;
  },
});

export const options = nconf.get()

running with this you'd end up with an object :
{
  bar: {
    baz: true,
    count: 34,
  },
  really: {
    kaboom: 9000
  }
}

now, I also have a schema that describes the envvars:
type Config = {
  BAR_BAZ: boolean;
  BAR_COUNT: number;
  REALLY_KABOOM: number;
}

The question here is this: how to make the nconf output typesafe according to the schema i have?
import { options } from './options.ts';

function somethingElseUseful(yesno: boolean) {
  ...something
}

export function usefulFunction() {
  return somethingElseUseful(options.bar.count)  // should throw type error that it only accepts boolean and not numbers.
}

I imagine the solution would involve some nifty usage of typescript "template literal types"

Write your own type predicate and assert options as type Config

Are you asking to do this for nconf in general? Or just for the particular transformation you're describing? Assuming it's the latter, does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz yes :) good work. write it up and lets accept it.

Note that deeply recursive types like Transform presented below tend to have bizarre edges and modifying them can sometimes require a significant refactoring.  This type was written to handle the test case from the question.  You might find that some use case fails to be handled properly, and if so, be prepared to have to tweak or even completely rewrite Transform.

The way I'd approach this is to take a type like {A_B_C: X, D_E_F: Y, G_H_I: Z} and make each key lowercase like {a_b_c: X, d_e_f: Y, g_h_i: Z}, and then for each property, compute a "deep record" type and intersect them all together, like {a:{b:{c: X}}} & {d:{e:{f: Y}}} & {g:{h:{i: Z}}}, and finally collapse those intersections into a single type.  Let's work on each piece of that:

In order to turn an entry like "bar_baz" and boolean into {bar: {baz: boolean}} you can write a recursive conditional DeepRecord<K, V> type:
type DeepRecord<K extends string, V> = K extends `${infer K0}_${infer KR}` ?
  Record<K0, DeepRecord<KR, V>> : Record<K, V>;

That uses template literal types to split the key K at underscore characters. So DeepRecord<"a_b_c", X> would be {a: {b: {c: X}}}.

Combining an intersection of object types into a single object type involves recursively computing an "identity" mapped type:
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object ?
  { [K in keyof T]: ExpandRecursively<T[K]> } : T;

which is similar to the definition from How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type? ), and transforming each entry into an intersection can be done like

And then we can put that together like this:
type Transform<T extends object> =
  { [K in string & keyof T]: (x: DeepRecord<Lowercase<K>, T[K]>) => void } extends
  Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? ExpandRecursively<I> : never;

We're mapping over the string keys of keyof T, and then for each key K, we use the Lowercase<T> utility type to convert each key to lowercase before computing the deep record. Once we have that deep record we put it in a contravariant type position as the parameter of a function, so that when we infer from it into a new type variable I, it is inferred as the intersection, as described in Transform union type to intersection type.  And then finally we ExpandRecursively that I  type to combine it.
Yes, this is kind of a lot of type juggling, but that's what you have to do for it to work.

Let's test it out:
type Config = {
  BAR_BAZ: boolean;
  BAR_COUNT: number;
  REALLY_KABOOM: number;
}

type Z = Transform<Config>;
/* type Z = {
    bar: {
        baz: boolean;
        count: number;
    };
    really: {
        kaboom: number;
    };
} */

Looks good.
Playground link to code

to service everyone else using SO as a shared brain, we should probs put your "caveat: recursive things" up the top?
